# issue with fortigate vpn using windows native vpn client: Overlay Controller VPN communication error (Members)

Tags: windows, networking, fortigate

So yesterday we put into production a new vpn connection using a fortigate rugged 30d as the server and a windows server 2016 as the client using the windows native VPN client.

It was working for the past 24 hours, but then this morning it wouldn't connect.

On the Fortigate side, the error in the VPN events log is:

```
Overlay Controller VPN communication error (Members)
```

On the Windows side the error is:

```
Can't connect to VPN
The network connection between your computer and the VPN server could not be established because the remote server is not responding. This could be because of one of the network devices (e.g, firewalls, NAT, routers, etc) between your computer and the remote server is not configured to allow VPN connections.
```

On the fortigate side I just used the Ipsec wizard to setup a remote access vpn for windows native vpn client.

To get this set up on the windows side I did the following:

- Enabled IKE/IPSEC keying module in windows services, set to automatic start.
- Enabled IPSEC policy agent in windows services, set to automatic start.
- Configured the AssumeUDPEncapsulationContextOnSendRule registry key.

The odd thing about this is we are not using the overlay controller vpn service on the fortigate side, and everything was working for about 24 hours until it would not connect anymore.

Forgive me if I am missing something obvious but I am relatively new to the Fortigate environment. We went with this unit because it needed to be in a "rugged" environment.

Please let me know if you have a solution to this or can point me in the right direction.

Thank you!